# append or remove item from list once toggle is apply active or disactive?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var materials = [];
  var limit = $("#upper").val();
  $("#upper").change(function() {
    limit = $(this).val();

  });

  $(".u").click(function() {
    var color = $(this).attr('data-color');
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    
    if (limit > $('.upper :not(.u)').length) 
    {
      $(this).css('background', $(this).attr('data-color'));
      var $el = $(this).toggleClass("u");
      console.log("added");
    } else if (!$(this).hasClass('u')) {
      var $el = $(this).toggleClass("u");
      console.log("removed");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.u {
  background: #FFFFFF!important;
  color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="upper" type="number" min="1" max="9" class="tbox_style" value="1">

<div class="contents upper">
  <div class="u" id="am" data-color="red">Upper Material 1</div>
  <div class="u" id="bm" data-color="yellow">Upper Material 2</div>
  <div class="u" id="cm" data-color="blue">Upper Material 3</div>
</div>
<div class="hidden">
    <input type="hidden" name="u-selected" id="u-selected" value="">
 </div>
```

when upper set to 1 -> log `added` or `removed` works okay

Current problem is:

when upper change to 2 or more -> log `added` or `removed` work , unexpected ,as below running

[image]

My goal is :

- when the div is `highlight` then add into the list.
- when the div is `not highlight` then remove from the list.

Comment: Please explain the problem clearly.

Comment: you can change `upper` to 2 , then try to see when you activated the div , then you see the log `added` or `removed` is not work properly .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should separate the logic of handling normal case and boundary case (number of not-class-u exceed `limit`)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var materials = []
  var limit = $("#upper").val()
  $("#upper").change(function() {
    limit = $(this).val()
  })

  $(".u").click(function() {
    var color = $(this).attr("data-color")
    var id = $(this).attr("id")
    var numberOfNotClassU = $(".upper :not(.u)").length

    if (limit <= numberOfNotClassU) {
      if (!$(this).hasClass("u")) {
        var $el = $(this).toggleClass("u")
        console.log("removed")
      }
      return
    }

    if (!$(this).hasClass("u")) {
      var $el = $(this).toggleClass("u")
      console.log("removed")
    } else {
      $(this).css("background", $(this).attr("data-color"))
      var $el = $(this).toggleClass("u")
      console.log("added")
    }
  })
})
```

```css
.u {
  background: #FFFFFF!important;
  color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="upper" type="number" min="1" max="9" class="tbox_style" value="1">

<div class="contents upper">
  <div class="u" id="am" data-color="red">Upper Material 1</div>
  <div class="u" id="bm" data-color="yellow">Upper Material 2</div>
  <div class="u" id="cm" data-color="blue">Upper Material 3</div>
</div>
<div class="hidden">
  <input type="hidden" name="u-selected" id="u-selected" value="">
</div>
```